# Azure Table Storage query by rowkey with leading zero

Tags: linq, azure, storage, azure-storage

I have a storage table in Azure with the following primary and row keys (not really, just an example) and retrieve the whole table as a list of TableEntities:

"partitionkey", "00"

"partitionkey", "01"

"partitionkey", "10"

"partitionkey", "11"

"partitionkey", "20"

"partitionkey", "21"

When I query the list like so:

```
var myItem = 

(from item in list

where item.RowKey == "00"

select item).FirstOrDefault();
```

myItem returns null. The same is true if I query for RowKey == "01".

But when I query by RowKey alone with any string which does NOT have a leading "0", I get the expected result. Also, if I query using any PartitionKey and the RowKey HAS a leading "0":

```
var myItem = 

(from item in list

where item.PartitionKey == "partitionkey" && item.RowKey == "00"

select item).FirstOrDefault();
```

I will also get the expected result.

If RowKeys in Azure Table Storage are strings, why does a string with a leading "0" matter?

Has anybody else run into this and if so, is it a bug?

Comment: Approximately how many entities are there in your table?

Comment: That looks very strange.  Have you tried grabbing a Fiddler capture to see if the LINQ query is generating the correct REST API query against Table Storage?

Comment: approximately 20 entries is all

Answer (score 0):

> Has anybody else run into this and if so, is it a bug?

According to your description, it seems that there is no suitable entity in the list when 
`myItem` returns null. You could try to output the entities in the list

```
foreach (var item in list)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}", item.PartitionKey, item.RowKey,);
}
```

I test with following code, it works correctly on my side. I **can't reproduce** the issue you mentioned

```
 CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse("storage connectionstring");
 // Create the table client.
 CloudTableClient tableClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient();
 // Create the CloudTable object that represents the "test" table.
 CloudTable table = tableClient.GetTableReference("test");
 TableQuery<TableEntity> query = new TableQuery<TableEntity>().Where(TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("PartitionKey",QueryComparisons.Equal, "partitionkey"));
 var list = table.ExecuteQuery(query);
 var myItem = (from item in list
               where item.RowKey == "00"
               select item).FirstOrDefault();
```

Test result:

[image]

Comment: Thank everyone for your responses - turned out to be a logic error on my part. There were multiple results, the first of which was null. Developer with a brain fart!